# Creating Featured Content Boxes

Tags: plugins, customization, navigation

I know there are plenty of plugins to do sliders out there but I'm looking for something slightly different and I've come up with no luck for a solution.

Basically, what I am trying to accomplish is to have a set of images (thinking of around 4) that sits statically above my content. Preferably it would pull the featured image and the title from posts with a specific tag or category and list them up there. Basically, a slider that doesn't slide I suppose.

I've included a screenshot of what I mean. Does anyone know of a plugin that would achieve this or a good tutorial on creating something like this?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing can be accomplished with [Featured Image](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails) and a simple [wp_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Usage) call.

These are very core elements of a WordPress theme. You'd need to define a size with [add image size](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size), and then call it up using the aforementioned post_thumbnail.

Your loop might look something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 3
);

$loop = new wp_Query($args);

while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">';
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'my_size');
    echo '</a>';
endwhile;

wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Thanks, that displays them great. How would I limit it to a specific category or tag?

Comment: look up `tax_query` parameter on the wp_query page I linked to above.